# How to add search box in a grafana dashboard for a table pannel?

Tags: data-visualization, grafana, grafana-variable

I have a table view in grafana with multiple data inside it like IP , HOSTNAME etc. How can i add a search box to enter IP in that box and it will retrive data from that table and show .
(Working with varibale feature but have to search IP and then select )